# Не грузится картинка

Tags: php, mysql

Написал скрипт загрузки картинки в базу (в БД путь, картинка в каталоге). Все хорошо прописывается только картинка в каталоге не появляется. Может что не так делаю? Привожу кусок кода отвечающего за загрузку....

```
if ($erro!=true){
$file=$_POST['myfile']['name'];
$dir='http://localhost/bol/img/';
$up_file=$dir.basename($file);
echo ($up_file);
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']))
{
$n=mt_rand(0,997);
$file_path=$dir.$n.jpeg;
if (!file_exists($file_path))
{
$_FILES['myfile']['name']=$n.'.'.jpeg;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'],$dir.$_FILES['myfile']['name']);
$put=$dir.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
}
dbConnect();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO image (put, nazv,opis,kto_kuda) VALUES ('{$put}','{$nazv}','{$opis}','{$kto_kuda}')") or die (mysql_error());
}}
```

Загрузка происходит через форму (`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`)

Comment: Ты в базу хочешь загружать картинки ?

Comment: Написано же - в базе только путь указывается а картинка сама лежит в каталоге. Каталог создан. img.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir='http://localhost/bol/img/';
```

Почему у Вас указан полный путь с протоколом?
Попробуйте изменить на

```
$dir='./bol/img/';
```

Answer (score 1):

Idaho37 прав. Вы указываете не правильный путь.
Вот работающий пример

```
include("core.php");
$panels = new panel;
echo '<a href="javascript:self.close()">закрыть окно</a> ';
if($panels->checkauth())
{
    echo '<html>
        <body>
        <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="" METHOD=POST>
        <h4>Разрешено загружать только фотографии<br />Выберете файл не (больше 1мб):</h4>
        <table><tr><td>Задать имя фотографии:</td><td>
        <input type="text" size="32" name="img_name" /></td></tr><tr><td>
        Выберить:</td><td>
        <INPUT NAME="myfile" TYPE="file"></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 align=right>
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Загрузить"></td></tr></table>
        </FORM>
        </body>
        </html>';
    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
    {
        //Настройки Upload-а
        $maxsize = 1024*1024*1; //Больше 1мб не может
        $valid_types =  array("image/png", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/jpeg");
        $dir="content_images/";

        //Обычные переменные
        $myfile = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
        $myfile_name = $dir.time()."_".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        $myfile_size = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
        $myfile_type = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
        $error_flag = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
        if(strlen($_POST['img_name'])==0)
        $img_nm="No Name";
        else
        $img_nm=$_POST['img_name'];

        if($error_flag == 0)
        {
            if($maxsize>$myfile_size)
            {
                // if(in_array($myfile_type, $valid_types))
                // {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $myfile_name))
                    {
                            $image=new Imagick();
                            $image->readImage($myfile_name);

                            include("mysql_class.php");
                            $mysql = new db;
                            if($mysql->query_insert("INSERT INTO pr_image (u_id, image_url, image_name, adddate) VALUES('".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$myfile_name."', '".$img_nm."','".time()."')"))
                            {
                                print("Ссылка на файл: ".$myfile_name." <br />");
                                print("MIME-тип файла: ".$myfile_type."<br>");
                                print("Размер файла: ".(round($myfile_size/1024))." kb <br><br>");
                                echo '<br /><img width=500px src="'.$myfile_name.'"';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                unlink($myfile_name);
                                echo "<h2>Ошибка Базы Данных</h2>";
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unlink($myfile);
                        echo "<h2>Ошибка Сервера</h2>";
                    }
                // }
                // else
                // {
                    // unlink($myfile);
                    // echo "<h2>Это не Фотография</h2>";
                // }
            }
            else
                {
                    unlink($myfile);
                    echo "<h2>Файл привышает 1мб!</h2>";
                }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<font color=red>Пожалуйста Авторизируйтесь</font>";
}
```